# Set convergence tolerance for scipy.optimize.minimize(method='L-BFGS-B')

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

This page (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html) describes the solver options one can pass to the L-BFGS-B' method of scipy's optimization package. 
I am trying to set the solver exit tolerance.

The docs mention two options, the one I would have preffered to use is 'factr', where the solver exits when:
`(f^k - f^{k+1})/max{|f^k|,|f^{k+1}|,1} <= factr * eps` (where epsilon is machine precision). However when I run my code is get a warning:

> OptimizeWarning: Unknown solver options: factr

So I presumed this option has been deprecated in favour of ftol (not sure why it would be though?). ftol being a specified number (i.e. diff <= n rather than <= n * machine_error).

That's fine by me, however the exit message I get for the solver is

> CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH

which suggests the L-BFGS-B routine is still using some value of factr which I do not know, and seemingly can't specify. Might be an overlooked mistake in the code, might be I've missed some way of passing options. Does anyone who uses this popular solver know a workaround?

Thanks

I've opened an issue on scipy github repository as well.

Comment: One question is if your installed version of scipy matches that of the docs... Many packages don't have the latest version. On the other hand, it is still referenced in the v0.16.0 docs, the latest. I note that the call has changed from 0.13, where options were listed separately, and 0.16 where you have a options={'eps': 1e-08...} structure.  In addition, although factr is listed as an option, it is not in the example call...

Comment: I am using scipy 0.16.0. You are right, there are several discrepancies in the docs. But the discrepancy I want to work around is that the factr option has been removed from the ui but still used by the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, `factr` is still computed ([in this line of code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py#L250)).

You can simply use something like

```
myfactr = 1e2
r = scipy.optimize.minimize(..., options={'ftol' : myfactr * np.finfo(float).eps)
```

if you still want to specify rather a value for `factr` instead of `ftol` directly.